# Randomly selecting an object property

Tags: actionscript-3, object, random, properties, selection

I guess a step back is in order.  My original question is at the bottom of this post for reference.

I am writing a word guessing game and wanted a way to:
1. Given a word length of 2 - 10 characters, randomly generate a valid english word  to guess
2.given a 2 - 10 character guess, ensure that it is a valid english word.
I created a vector of 9 objects, one for each word length and dynamically created 172000
property/ value pairs using the words from a word list to name the properties and setting their value to true. The inner loop is:

```
for (i = 0; i < _WordCount[wordLength] - 2; i) 
{
    _WordsList[wordLength]["" + _WordsVector[wordLength][i++]] = true;
}
```

To validate a word , the following lookup returns true if valid:

```
function Validate(key:String):Boolean
{
    return  _WordsList[key.length - 2][key]
}
```

I transferred them from a vector to objects to take advantage of the hash take lookup of the properties. Haven't looked at how much memory this all takes but it's been a useful learning exercise.
I just wasn't sure how best to randomly choose a property from one of the objects. I was thinking of validating whatever method I chose by generating 1000 000 words and analyzing the statistics of the distribution.
So I suppose my question should really first be  am I better off using some other approach such as keeping the lists in vectors and doing a search each time ?

---

Original question

Newbie first question:

I read a thread that said that traversal order in a for.. in is determined by a hash table and appears random.

I'm looking for a good way to randomly select a property in an object. Would the first element in a for .. in traversing the properties, or perhaps the random nth element in the iteration be truly random. I'd like to ensure that there is approximately an equal probability of accessing a given property. The Objects have between approximately 100 and 20000 properties. Other approaches ?

thanks.

Comment: How do you organize your properties? And also why do you need a random one? What if it'll be a stage reference - it's also a property?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scenario you described in your edited question, I'd suggest using a `Vector.<String>` and your map object.

You can store all your keys in the vector and map them in the object, then you can select a random numeric key in the vector and use the result as a key in the map object.

To make it clear, take a look at this simple example:

```
var keys:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
var map:Object = { };

function add(key:String, value:*):void
{
    keys.push(key);
    map[key] = value;
}

function getRandom():*
{
    var randomKey = keys[int(Math.random() * keys.length)];

    return map[randomKey];
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
add("a", "x");
add("b", "y");
add("c", "z");

var radomValue:* = getRandom();
```

---

**Using `Object` instead of `String`**

Instead of storing the strings you can store objects that have the string inside of them,
something like:

```
public class Word
{
    public var value:String;
    public var length:int;

    public function Word(value:String)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.length = value.length;
    }
}
```

Use this object as value instead of the string, but you need to change your map object to be a [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html):

```
var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function add(key:Word, value:*):void
{
    keys.push(key);
    map[key] = value;
}
```

This way you won't duplicate every word (but will have a little class overhead).

Comment: Hi NemoStein Thank you for your detailed response. I think what you suggest is more or less what I have now. The 2D _WordsVector I use to create the _WordsList Objects contains 9 vectors of strings, for each length from 2-10. Because I have 172000 words that take about 1.7Mb I want to avoid if possible keeping 2 copies of the words. When  the parameter is created it looks like a copy of the word is made. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @user3657, I've modified my answer.